# Invalid object when selecting from temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a temporary table called `#PrevStatus`. I've confirmed that the create statement is correct.

When I run,

```
exec (@TableQuery)
```

which contains the table create statement and then right after

```
select * from #PrevStates
```

I get,

```
Invalid object name '#PrevStatus'
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: "Why is this happening?" because local temporary tables are dropped automatically when they go out of scope. Is there an implicit second part to this question "What can I do about it?" if so please show more code or give us some context as to why you are creating it dynamically and how you are using it afterwards.

Comment: EXEC statement crates objects in a separate session, which scope is out of your current session. Either you need to use globally scoped object with ## prefix or modify your code and get rid of dynamic SQL.

Comment: @yahor NO, please do not use ## as a workaround. This means two different people running at the same time will have conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I think the ## workaround will work just fine.

Comment: Ok, see you back here when two people try to run this code at the same time. Why don't you just put the select inside the exec()? Or explain why you are creating the #temp table dynamically in the first place (maybe we can help you fix that)?

Comment: I see what you are saying. The table will only live for the time of the query.  If I give it a unique name when creating it and then drop it when the query is done, that should fix the problem.

Comment: If you are going to give it a unique name when creating it how will you reference it? More dynamic SQL?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - why not to name them unique per session? ##GUIDString_ObjectName?

Comment: That's true. I'm creating a dynamic table for the following reason. I have a set of equipment names. Those equipment names can vary based on what parameters a person uses.

Comment: Because of what Martin asked - if you are going to have to name it with a GUID, then any future references will have to construct the name dynamically as well, so what have you gained? If everything is all in one big block of dynamic SQL, just use #name because this won't conflict with any other sessions.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - i agree, that was silly comment from my side. I would just see the create table statement - just curious why one is needed to be dynamic. Generally if you create an object in current the session it's accessible later in dynamic sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option which I've used before is to create the temp table using some known fields that will always be the same, then alter the temp table using dynamic SQL to add in the additional columns that you only need in specific cases.  This way the temp table is created within scope, then altered via dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (ID int identity(1,1) primary key)

if @Something = 1 then
begin
     set @sql = 'alter table #MyTable add column ...'
     exec (@sql)
end
...
Your dynamic select statement goes down here somewhere.
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the solution that will work best with my situation.

Comment: This doesn't really seem any less complicated than creating the #table in dynamic SQL and then running the select in the same block of dynamic SQL.

Comment: About the only different is that the code isn't all red.